# How to pass a package flag with cabal tool?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I had a command line with `stack`:

```
stack --flag "cryptonite:-integer-gmp" build
```

How to pass the same flag with `cabal`?

Is this attempt correct (at least it does not fail):

```
cabal --flags="cryptonite -integer-gmp" build  # space instead of ':'
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--flags` sets flags for the local package, so `--flags="cryptonite -integer-gmp` means "enable the flag `cryptonite` and disable `integer-gmp` for my package", which is not what you mean.

The right command-line option is `--constraint="cryptonite -integer-gmp"`. You can have multiple `--constraint` options for more than one package. (See also [Cabal User Guide: `--constraint`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup-commands.html#cmdoption-runhaskell-Setup.hs-configure-constraint).)

Or you can set it in `cabal.project`. (See also [Cabal User Guide: `flags` in `cabal.project`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-flags).)

```
-- cabal.project

packages: .

package cryptonite
  flags: -integer-gmp
```

Comment: Just checked, yes, it works, no any GNU MP fingerprints.